# How to Twice including a php file within a php file

Tags: php, web-applications

So i have a php file called address.php which contains code to validate the users address . On this page i `require_once` a file called left_navigation.php which i used to render my left tool bar . .

Now after editing the  address when the user clicks the confirm button i want to reload the left_navigation.php file as my left tool bar contents should change ..

I am new to php so what is the best way to do this ? i.e twice include a php file

Comment: For this case use [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and not `require_once`.

Comment: yes @air4x i tried that . However the file left_navigation.php contains some function definitions . So i end up including them twice :/ So it gives an error ...

Comment: if you want to reload the whole page or the partial left side navigation only

Comment: @ScoRpion... i want to reload only the left side toolbar . that is enough to update the left tool bar with new updated information .

Comment: @rockstar You need to learn AJAX for partial page update

Comment: either move the function declarations to a new file or put them inside [`function_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) like `if (!function_exists('foo')) { function foo() {} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reload only the left side you need to read Ajax first. [Here is a Beginners Guide](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) to start with. you can't partially update a part of a web page with out Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If the user clicks on a button the page normally loads again. In this moment left_navigation.php is also read again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use include instead of require_once.

you can check on the jQuery .load() function, so when the user clicks your button, your left_navigation.php will be reloaded async. with a little line of code.

```
$('#left_navigation').load('left_navigation.php');
```

assuming the left_navigation.php file is contained inside a div as follows:

```
<div id="left_navigation">
   <?php
       include('left_navigation.php');
   ?>
</div>
```

check the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/load/